# After installing Ubuntu on my previously windows laptop, my second hard drive disappeared. How can I access it?

Tags: hard-drive, windows-10

so I've backed everything up from both my hard drives, but the second drive doesn't show up at all and I'm wondering what happened to it and how I can access it? At this point there's a large chunk of storage space that is useless because I can't find it.
Any help in figuring out what happened to and accessing the second disk would be much appreciated.
I am new to Linux (< 2 months)
When I was running windows it was disk D://
I thought Ubuntu would only affect drive C://

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1320150/edit) to show us the complete output of `sudo blkid` and of `df -h`

Answer (score 0):

The first and easiest step to take is run `lsblk` from the terminal and see if there are any drives listed that are not mounted.  If your lucky it will be listed and just not mounted in that case you can simple mount the drive with the command `sudo mount /dev/device-name /location/to/mount`.  If your unable to mount the drive or it is not listed confirm the `ntfs-3g` package is installed.  If it was not installed install it reboot and repeat the process.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I ran the code and could not see the drive listed. I'll check the ntfs-3g package installation next chance I get and hope that works.